# Count occurrenses from a txtfile

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am making a simple form with a button. When comCount (the button) is clicked i want my program to open a txt file and return the text in a table (tblResults) and show the count of each value from the .txt .. (animals.txt)

The input in the .txt file looks like this

```
Cat
Cat
Dog
Bird
Fish
Cat
Dog
```

And so on. Just one animal per line

I don't know how to do this, so if anyone could help me along, i would be grateful.
The tblResult should then return

```
Cat 3
Dog 2
Bird 1
Fish 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Here is a suggestion on how to improve your question and have it re-opened: You can create a linked table in Access that points to a text file. Check out the information [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/import-or-link-to-data-in-a-text-file-HA001232227.aspx), then [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19761355/edit) your question to indicate *what you have tried*, and *what your specific question is*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub comCount_Click()
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim sAnimal As String
    Dim sQuery As String
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rsSQL As DAO.Recordset
    Dim iCount As Integer

    Set dbs = CurrentDb

    sFileName = "C:\Animals.txt" 'Enter your full path here
    Open sFileName For Input As #1

    While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, sAnimal
        sQuery = "Select * from tblResults where AnimalName = """ & sAnimal & """"
        Set rsSQL = dbs.OpenRecordset(sQuery)
        If rsSQL.RecordCount = 0 Then
            rsSQL.AddNew
                rsSQL.Fields("AnimalName") = sAnimal
                rsSQL.Fields("AnimalCount") = 1
            rsSQL.Update
        Else
            rsSQL.Edit
                Count = rsSQL.Fields("AnimalCount") + 1
                rsSQL.Fields("AnimalCount") = iCount
            rsSQL.Update
        End If
        rsSQL.Close
    Wend

    Close #1

End Sub
```

Also assuming you have two fields in your table, AnimalName and AnimalCount